# Jquery check all works not older than jquery 1.4.2

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have a question about checkboxes.

In the linked fiddles, I have 2 checkboxes. If I select both(car, bus) checkboxes, it must also select the "Checkall" checkbox.

Code that toggles the state:

```
$('.checkAll').change(function() {
    $('.chc').attr('checked', $( this ).is( ':checked' ) ? 'checked' :'');
});
```

Below it works perfect :(with *jquery-ui 1.9.1* and *jquery 1.4.2*)

Demo : **http://jsfiddle.net/nUwfB/**

But if i remove the *jquery 1.4.2* version and add *jquery 1.8.3*, it doesn't work:

Demo : **http://jsfiddle.net/dSCfp/**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The `.attr()` method](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) was changed (and no longer works with the `checked` property of checkboxes correctly in > v1.6).

> As of jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method returns undefined for attributes
>   that have not been set. In addition, .attr() should not be used on
>   plain objects, arrays, the window, or the document. To retrieve and
>   change DOM properties, use the .prop() method.

Use [the `.prop()` method](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead (which accepts a boolean, not a string).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.checkAll').change(function() {
        $('.chc').prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
    });

    $("#slctble").selectable({
        filter: 'td',
        cancel: 'td:not(.isaretle)',
        stop: function() {
            $(".ui-selected input", this).each(function() {
                this.checked = !this.checked
            }); //end-ui-selected input
            $('.chc').length == $('.chc:checked').length ? $('.checkAll').prop('checked', true) : $('.checkAll').prop('checked', false);
        } //endStopFunction
    }); //endSelectable
});​
```

Updated non-working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dSCfp/1/